# Overriding composer dependencies autoloading instructions

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a dependency in my Laravel project that requires phinx. Nowadays phinx also depends on cakephp core, which autoloads its global [helper functions](https://github.com/cakephp/core/blob/master/functions.php). Somehow cakephp functions get registered before the Laravel one's and that creates issues for me, since I rely on `env` function from Laravel for configuration and it works differently from Cake's function with the same name.

What I've tried:

- manually requiring Laravel's functions in my app bootstrap before requiring the autoloader (this solves that instance of the problem for me, but I'd like to find a better way if possible)
- specifying Laravel's helper functions file in my project's composer.json autoload section, hoping that it would somehow take precedence over the other one, but it doesn't seem to work. Prolly because the order of execution.

Is there obvious way to prevent this from happening? Dependencies registering global functions or at least preventing this specific instance from happening? Maybe some way to prevent autoloading certain files/classes in composer?

Comment: Got a recommendation today for this [package](https://github.com/mcaskill/composer-plugin-exclude-files). It seems to work.